# Cannot create directory in hdfs NameNode is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I upgrade to the latest version of cloudera.Now I am trying to create directory in HDFS

```
hadoop fs -mkdir data
```

Am getting the following error

> Cannot Create /user/cloudera/data Name Node is in SafeMode.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21):

When you start `hadoop`, for some time limit `hadoop` stays in `safemode`. You can either wait (you can see the time limit being decreased on `Namenode` web UI) until the time limit or You can turn it off with

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

The above command turns off the safemode of hadoop

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Ramesh Maharjan answer, By default, cloudera machine(Cloudera Quick Start#5.12) doesn't allow to SET OFF safe mode, it's required to specify the -u options as shown below:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was immediately using `hive` command to go into hive shell after starting hadoop using `start-all.sh`. I re-tried using `hive` command after waiting for 10-20 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Might need the full path to hdfs command

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```